# how to run a system call from a makefile and save the answer in a variable

Tags: c, shell, makefile, command

i am trying to set a variable's value to use during the compilation.
I try to do that in a separate makefile target

```
svnversion:
    SVN_REV=$(shell svnversion -cn | sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | grep '[0-9]')
    $(info svn_rev = $(SVN_REV))
```

I have read that this is the way to set the value of a variable. 
Yet when i run 'make' I see :

```
SVN_REV=613
svn_rev =
```

so the variable seems to be empty. Afterwards I expect that this variable will be present while the compilation takes place (in other targets). Is this the case? or should I add an 'export' command in the svnversion target? and how to I address the SVN_REV variable? $(SVN_REV) or $$(SVN_REV).

thank you

Comment: Could it be that variables are case-sensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually assigning the value SVN_REV in the subshell that is concluded at the end of the line,

what you probably want is:

```
svnversion:: SVN_REV=$(shell svnversion -cn | sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | grep '[0-9]')

svnversion:
        $(info svn_rev = $(SVN_REV))
```

This sets the variable when the target is set.

If this isn't what was intended, say you want to do some processing with the variable, then you need to make each line a continuation of the previous one using the horrible `; \` at the end of line semantics. If you are then referencing shell variables (like the one evaluated in your first line), then you need to use the `$$` syntax before the variable name

e.g.

```
svnversion:
        SVN_REV=$(shell svnversion -cn | sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | grep '[0-9]'); \
        echo svn_rev = $$SVN_REV
```

but because it's in a shell, you can't use the variable in the `$(info` command, as that takes place outside of the evaluation of the target.

Comment: could you please explain the `svnversion::` snipet? is it an extra target? when is it run?

Comment: When your target is `svnversion::`, you evaluate the variable SVN_REV

Comment: This allows mechanisms like `debug:: CFLAGS+=-g` adding to the CFLAGS variable within make

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variables between different lines in rules or even between different rules. Each line is being executed in it's own shell, so there's no way of passing informations this way. (Petesh stated that right now as I just see)

if you need to store intermediate informations, use files like this:

```
 foo:
         uname -m > current_arch
         ...

 bar:
         gcc -m $$(cat current_arch) ...
         ...
```

You may also set a macro if the command being executed is not too time-consuming and does not depend on when it is called during the build process:ant

```
 ARCH = $$(uname -m)

 bar:
         gcc -m $(ARCH) ...
```

But this is not a variable being set but a macro substitution. The actual command passed to the shell when calling `make bar` would be:

```
         gcc -m $(uname -n)
```

and *then* the uname command would be executed.